# amp-ad-xorigin-iframe-handler returned promise should trigger render-start on message "bootstrap-loaded" if render-start is NOT implemented FAILED

Tags: html, analytics, amp-html

Hi All,

I am new in AMP technology.
As I am trying to add new custom amp-analytics (Vendor analytics) in ampproject.
Following are the two exception ocure in build file 
Please help me to resolve the issue.

As per docs i have changed follwoing file in ampproject branch

analytics-vendors.amp.html,  analytics.amp.html, vendor-requests.json, vendors.js, amp-analytics.md

Auto build on github ampproject giving following error.

1. amp-ad-xorigin-iframe-handler init() returned promise should trigger render-start on message "bootstrap-loaded" if render-start is NOT implemented FAILED
                   Error: timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.

Thank in advance

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thanks @abielita for ur reply.Please have a look on my git repository:  https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/8245 and my amp-analytics id is ibeatanalytics